# Integrated Visual Studio List Workflow from Sharepoint hosted app issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I am trying to create the integrated visual studio workflows.
I am able to create integrated( i.e. accessible in the host web) site workflows but getting error for the list workflows.

When I install  app from the app catalog of my web application I am getting this error:

```
Type: Configuration(Contact admin)  
Component:Common App Deployment

Error: There was an error during the operation.
Details: EventSourceGUID

Correlation ID: 9d1171e4-24a4-4ac2-a177-ef8dbad3f237
```

I am using VS2013.

I have followed below link to create the workflow:

http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/09/integrated-workflow-apps-deploy.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. When creating an integrated list workflow, you cannot directly add it to a list and therefor you also cannot activate manual or automatic start of the workflow. This has to be done after the workflow is deployed. That was the problem in my case.
When I set the manual start and automatic start to false, the error disappeared.